# saving HTML source code for debugging in nightwatch.js

Tags: automated-tests, nightwatch.js

Suppose, I have a failing test in only one of the browsers, where one of the css/html elements is "not found".

Screenshot looks okay. How can I get the html source of the current document to check?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Nightwatch's wrapper for selenium function `source` ([DOC](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#source)), this can be accomplished relatively easily.

For instance:

```
browser
    .url("http://www.google.com")
    .source((result) => {
        // Source will be stored in result.value
        console.log(result.value);
    })
```